# Attached Property child node syntax

Tags: wpf, attached-properties

I have a Polygon in a Canvas that is normally defined like

```
<Polygon Points="0,0 0,24, 18,12" Fill="Red"
         Canvas.Left="44" Canvas.Top="-12" />
```

But I'd like to use a `MultiValueConverter` to determine the `Canvas.Left` value, but how do I specify the child node?

`<Polygon.(Canvas.Left)>` isn't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To assign an attached property as an inner tag you simply use the name of the attached property:

```
<Polygon>
    <Canvas.Left>
        <MultiBinding>
            ...
        </MultiBinding>
    </Canvas.Left>
</Polygon>
```

If you've worked with Blend and the interactions library, then you'd see this is exactly how it works there as well (here `Triggers` is in fact an attached property):

```
<Control>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        ...
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Control>
```